# avoiding a circular dependency in packaging

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I'm cleaning up some Python (2.7) code that I inherited, and have come across a circular import scenario that I'd like to get rid of.  The code currently runs (by abusing the import function), but it's a messy and causes issues when other code doesn't access it in a specific way.

The file structure is essentially this:

```
/deep/nested/path/__init__.py
/deep/nested/path/objects.py
/deep/nested/path/api.py
```

`objects` is a collection of data models

`api` exposes developer interface with functions to get/create instances of `objects`.

the circular import occurs because some `objects` need to invoke `api` functions to create child objects.

this section of code handles analytics and is executed a lot (many objects, deep recursion). the package namespace is fairly nested too -- so using the package path has a tangible effect on performance.

i'm very tempted to just move the factory functions needed by `objects` into that file, and then import them back into `api` for general use.  that would solve my problems (and eliminate a dot), but lose some of the code organization (which is actually pretty decent).  I'm hoping for another set of eyes to give some input.

while there are several questions about circular imports already here, i'm not concerned with getting this to work (which it does). i'm concerned with minimizing the dot notation.  `api.factory` and `objects.foo` work, but `package.api.factory` wont.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better to move those factory functions into a third
module. Then `objects` can import it to creates its objects; `api` can
import it if needed; other modules can import it if they need what it
contains.